# Error in the namenode, localhost during import of the file from hdfs

Tags: python, apache-spark, hdfs

I am using python-spark for a word count problem. My lines of codes for importing the text file located in my hdfs are:

```
file="hdfs://localhost:50070/user/hduser/input/sample.txt"
input=sc.textFile(file)
```

When I execute the program I get the following error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   o25.collect. : java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception:
>   com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message
>   end-group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details : local host
>   is: "quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1"; destination host is:
>   "localhost":50070;

Please help me to eradicate it. I am stuck.

Comment: are you sure that your hadoop is running ? type jps in terminal and make sure that the name node and datanodes are running.

Comment: I tried it when I wrote:

Comment: I wrote: [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ jps
6447 Jps

Comment: Oh sorry when I wrote like: [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ jps                          Then I got the following result:
6447 Jps                                                                                                 So is my hadoop  is running? Please suggest me.

Comment: I have two .txt files. Can I place two .txt files within the same   /user/hduser/input/  path or should I provide a different hdfs path for that .txt file

Comment: Your hadoop is not running, You should see a datanode and name node running with PIDs when you type jps command.

Comment: you can put more than one file in the input path for spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `input=sc.textFile(file)` where `file="/user/hduser/input/sample.txt"`

You don't need hdfs://localhost:50070/

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it works fine. Nut I want to know whether my file is still in that hdfs or in local file system and what is "jps". When I try to write: [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ jps in terminal I get the result as "6447 Jps". So id anything missing????

Comment: @RACHITAPATRO with `sc.textFile(file)` your file will still be in HDFS and it would return an RDD to the variable `input`.

Comment: `jps` would give you the JVMs process status which would help you check the status of your spark program. That would be independent of the error you were getting while reading a file from HDFS.

Comment: Ok Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have two .txt files. Can I place two .txt files within the same /user/hduser/input/ path or should I provide a different hdfs path for that .txt file

Comment: @RACHITAPATRO You can place as many files as you like inside a directory. While running the spark job use `file="/user/hduser/input/"` this will read all the files inside the `/input/` directory.